# Problems with overriding the values in a cls file

Tags: table-of-contents, templates, line-spacing

I'm writing a thesis and I'm trying to make the Table of Contents single spaced.
This question was asked before and I tried the following solution in my `.tex` file:

```
\begin{singlespace}
\tableofcontents
\end{singlespace}
```

but it didn't work (everything compiles fine but the Table of Contents is still double spaced). I looked into the `.cls` file I'm using - [`iitthesis.cls`](http://www.iit.edu/graduate_college/academic_affairs/pdfs/iitthesis) - which prefer not to change; I found this:

```
% \ssp : single-spacing
% \dsp : double-spacing
% \tsp : triple-spacing
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\@normalsize}
\def\ssp{\def\baselinestretch{1.0}\large\normalsize}
\def\dsp{\def\baselinestretch{1.66}\large\normalsize}
\def\tsp{\def\baselinestretch{2.6}\large\normalsize}
...
\def\tableofcontents{
 \begin{center}
 \dsp{TABLE OF CONTENTS\\}
 \end{center}
 \ssp
\hfill Page\@starttoc{toc}}
```

So, is it the case that `\dsp{TABLE OF CONTENTS\\}` is overriding `\begin{singlespace}`? And if yes, how do I solve this? Should I define `\tableofcontents` in my `.tex` file as a new command that will override the one in the `.cls` file?

Comment: Thanks Jon for you answer. I did what you suggested and found out that it's not even the dsp line. It's actually the \ssp line that determines that space, which means the table of contents should be single-spaced using this class. However, I see it as double-spaced, and when I change \ssp to \dsp it gets even worse, so now I need to figure out why single-space looks like double-space...

Comment: @jon Here it is: 
http://www.iit.edu/graduate_college/academic_affairs/pdfs/iitthesis

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem resides in the definition of `\Chapter`.  (The 'double spacing' is by design.)  It seems like a very strange `.cls` file, and I'm not certain about the precise nature of the problem you are having, but the following might be the fix you are looking for:

```
\renewcommand{\Chapter}[1]{%
  \clearpage  
  \noindent 
  \refstepcounter{chapter} 
  \begin{center}   
    \dsp{CHAPTER\space\thechapter\\} 
    \vspace{10pt}       
     \ssp\uppercase{#1}     
     \vspace{-5pt}    
     \end{center}             
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect%\vspace*{3pt}%  <--- commented out 
} 
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect
     \makebox[0.75in][r]{\thechapter.}\hspace*{3pt} \uppercase{#1}}
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect%\vspace*{10pt}%  <--- commented out
}
}
```

For what it's worth, this seems like a pretty hacky way to get a chapter command up and running.  If it is possible, you may want to consider using a more up to date (and much more flexible) document class --- although this may be out of your control.

Comment: it didn't fix the problem but thanks for trying! I think you're right, I should use a different document class.

Comment: @user247866 -- Well, it is very difficult to fix 'the' problem when you don't post an example for others to use.  I think this solution fixes *a* 'problem' (like I said, the double spacing is by design), but it's hard for me to know whether it is yours....